# Can't deccode url link "Health%20&%20Beaut" to "Health & Beauty"

Tags: laravel, decode

I try anyway to decode
http://mywebsite/product/get_product?lv1=Health%20&%20Beaut
I use `html_entity_decode(Health%20&%20Beaut)`

I want get "Health & Beauty"
But this get 
Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use php's `urldecode`...

PHP:

```
$x = "Health%20&%20Beaut";
echo urldecode($x);
```

Output:

```
Health & Beaut
```

See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b0ba927391a55b2bf0d9716998f35853e26e7b4

Comment: `urldecode` gives the exact output you require!

    $x = "Health%20&%20Beaut";
    echo urldecode($x);


http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49270fe516ba14682be40c5ebb30224dbe042f4b

Comment: Thanks you very much bcz support me enthusiasm.
Example: I have a link:
`mysite.com/product/get_product_by_level?lv1=Health%20&%20Beaut`
In laravel i use `urldecode($request->lv1)`, it not return "Health & Beaut", it return "Health ". 
You have any way? Thanks ^^

Comment: Its likely tripping up on the &, you should either remove, replace, or properly encode it.

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript global function [decodeURIComponent(uri)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

Comment: Thanks.Yes it return "Health & Beauty", but I wan't use PHP ^^

Comment: You are enthusiasm. Thanks